# Data mining with SSRS in SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How Could I make data mining with a report possible. I know basic SQL and managed to make some static tables but I want to be able to click on an item and have a more detailed table on just that item or related things( a table of past versions ) ext...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want are drill-down reports. What you need is a summary report (say, sales per person) and a detailed report (say, sales by person per product group). The detailed report will have a Person report parameter that will be provided by the summary report.

On the summary report, on the person table cell, right-click, choose Properties and select the navigation tab. Select "Jump to report", drop-down and select your detailed report and click the Parameters... button. In the Parameter Name column, drop down and select the person parameter and in the Parameter Value column drop down and select the Person field.

Now when you run the summary report you can click through on the person cell and display that person's results on the detail report.

You can also pass through the parameters (say, a date range) that were entered on the summary report to the detail report parameters by using the expression =Parameters!MyParamName.Value rather than a field expression.